# how to access sites without specifying port number in the url, after creating virtual host in Bitnami lampstack for ubuntu 14

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, zend-framework, virtualhost

Can some one please help me to create a virtual host in Bitnami Lampstack, which is installed on ubuntu 14.0.4, through which I can access my site without specifying port number  in the URL as- `http://mysite.local` instead of `http://mysite.local:8080` ?

I have Bitnami Lampstack 5.3.29 (64 bit) installed on my system (ubuntu 14.0.4). I have configured the virtual host file as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/home/qainfotech/lampstack-5.3.29-0/apache2/htdocs/mysite/htdocs"
    ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

which allow me access the home page of my site very easily by the URL `http://mysite.loca:8080` but the home page it doesn't redirect properly.

So how can I configure virtual host to access my site without specifying port number in the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/qainfotech/lampstack-5.3.29-0/apache2/htdocs/mysite/htdocs"
    ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Defaut HTTP port is port 80.
So when you don't specify a port in your url, you are using port 80.

Comment: I cannot use port 80. It is occupied by some other applications.